# What are a few tips for optimizing go (golang) code when using slices (or arrays) of bytes?

Tags: arrays, string, performance, optimization, go

I waw wondering what could be some of the common pitfalls that a novice go programmer could fall in when writing (unintentionally slow go code).

1) First, I know that in python doing string concatenation can be (or used to be expensive), is that the same in go when trying to add one element to a string? As in "hello"+"World".

2) The other issue is that I find myself very often having to extend my slice with a list of more bytes (rather than 1 byte at a time). I have a "dirty" way of appending it by doing the following:

`newStr := string(arrayOfBytes) + string(newBytesToAppend)`

Is that way slower than just doing something like?

```
for _, b := range newBytesToAppend{
    arrayOfBytes = append(arrayOfBytes, b)
}
```

Or is there a better way to append whole slices to other slices or maybe a built in way? It just seems to me a little odd that I would even have to write my own extend function (or even benchmark it)

Also, sometimes I end up having to loop through every element of the byte slice and for readability, I change the type of that current byte to a string. As in:

```
for _, b := range newBytesToAppend{
    c := string(b)
    //some more logic on c
    logic(c) //logic
}
```

3) I was wondering, if **converting types** in go is expensive (specially between string to arrays) and if that might be one of the factors that might be making the code slow. Btw, sometimes I change types (to strings) **very** often, nearly every iteration.

But more generally, I was trying to search for the web a list of hints of what often are things that makes go code slow and was trying to change it so that it wouldn't (but didn't have that much luck). I am very much aware that this depends from application to application, but was wondering if there are any "expert" advice on what usually makes "novice" go code slow.

4) The last thing I can think of is, that sometimes I do know in advance the length of the slice, so I could just use arrays with fixed length. Could that change anything?

5) I have also made my own types as in:

```
type Num int
```

or

```
type Name string
```

Do those hinder performance?

6) Is there a general list of heuristic to watch out in go for code optimization? For example, is dereferencing a problem as it can be in C?

Comment: You can easily test some of your questions by benchmarking your code. That sounds painful, but it really isn't. Go has benchmarking built in. Have a look here: http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go. Also, appending a slice to another slice can be achieved with the variadic operator: `slice1 = append(slice1, slice2...)`.

Comment: Please don't pose several questions as one question.

Comment: @peterSO I guess I didn't write my question very well, but the goal of my question was trying to get at different ideas/heuristics of what does wrong/slow in go-code often. I was just looking for some advice of how go code could be optimized in general, so thats why I threw in some of the different ideas that I had. The reason I wrote multiple ideas in one question was to guide answers of the general things that could be useful or things that I could think of that could be optimized in go code in general. Maybe the problem could be that the question is too general.

Answer (score 3):

Use `bytes.Buffer` / `Buffer.Write`, it handles re-sizing the internal slice for you and it's by far the most effiecent way to manage multiple `[]byte`s.

About the 2nd question, it's rather easy to answer that using a simple benchmark.

Comment: For example, if you are reading from a network connection implemented by `net`, does one necessarily have to use a temporary buffer when one wants to write to `bytes.Buffer` (i.e. have two buffers, one []byte and another bytes.Buffer)? it seems wasteful to me to have to copy bytes around twice. Of bytes.Buffer is not usually used when dealing with connections?

Comment: Highly depends on what you need, if you gonna be appending buffers around, yes using bytes.Buffer is the way to go.